# The data which is entered is not getting stored and no error is shown

Tags: java, android, sql

I was trying to create a small android application which takes login and signup. I am new to android application development. please help me solve this problem.

When i click on signup button nothing is happening(no error is shown) and data which is entered is not getting stored. I don't understand what is happening.

```
package com.example.savepassword;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class Signup_form extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText Name;
private EditText Email;
private EditText Password;
private EditText Re_Password;
private EditText Mobile_Number;
private EditText Country;
private Button Signup;
DatabaseHelper db;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_form);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Name = findViewById(R.id.EtName);
    Email = findViewById(R.id.Etemail);
    Password = findViewById(R.id.Etpassword);
    Re_Password = findViewById(R.id.EtRe_password);
    Mobile_Number = findViewById(R.id.Etphone);
    Country = findViewById(R.id.EtCountry);
    Signup = findViewById(R.id.BtnSignup);

    Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = Name.getText().toString();
            String email = Email.getText().toString();
            String password = Password.getText().toString();
            String re_password = Re_Password.getText().toString();
            String mobile_number = Mobile_Number.getText().toString();
            int mobile_number1 = Integer.parseInt(mobile_number);
            String country = Country.getText().toString();
            validateEmail(email);
            validatePassword(password);

            if (name.equals("") || re_password.equals("") || country.equals("") || mobile_number.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields cannot be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (password.equals(re_password)) {
                Boolean chkemail = db.checkEmail(email);
                if (chkemail == true) {
                    Boolean insert = db.insert(email, password, name, mobile_number1, country);
                    if (insert == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        openHomePage();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


}

private void openHomePage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private Boolean validateEmail(String email) {
    email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        Email.setError("Please Enter your Email Id");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        Email.setError("Please Enter a valid Email Id");
        return false;
    } else {
        Email.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}

private Boolean validatePassword(String password) {
    password = Password.getText().toString().trim();

    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        Password.setError("Please Enter your Password");
        return false;
    } else {
        Password.setError(null);
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

This is the database that I have created using SQL.

```
package com.example.savepassword;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create table user(Username text, email text primary key, password text, mobilenumber integer, country text)");
    try {
        db.execSQL("some invalid SQL");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("onCreate","Error creating table: "+e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists user");


}
//    inserting in database
public boolean insert(String Username, String email, String password, int mobileno, String country) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("username", Username);
    contentValues.put("email", email);
    contentValues.put("password", password);
    contentValues.put("mobile_number", mobileno);
    contentValues.put("country", country);
    long ins = db.insert("user", null, contentValues);
    if (ins == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//    Check if email exists
public Boolean checkEmail(String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where email=?", new String[]{email});

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//    Checking the email and password while login
public Boolean checkemailpassword(String email, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where email=? and password=?", new String[]{email, password});

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you want `Create table user(Username name,` to be `Create table user(username text not null,` - most likely the create table is failing because `name` is not a column type.  (Always check return status when it is available or catch and log SQLException.)

Comment: I have changed it. And the signup button still does nothing.

Comment: Also this is incorrect: `contentValues.put("mobile_number", mobileno);` - column name doesn't match create table name (`mobilenumber`) assuming you haven't modified it.  So your insert fails - which happens to be the one path that does not produce a toast (or any logging).

Comment: Better to use room database in android.Refer the link "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase" & "https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room"

Comment: Can you please check if there are any errors in the signup activity. I feel like there is something not right in the signup activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong type '**name**' to create `user` table. You should change your table create query like below:

```
db.execSQL("Create table user(Username text, email text primary key, password text, mobilenumber integer, country text)");
```

Comment: I have changed it. And the signup button still does nothing.

Comment: Delete your application from device/emulator if already installed and try

Comment: Any toast is not shown. And I checked the Login.db database. Nothing is stored.

Comment: Can you please check if there are any errors in the signup activity. I feel like there is something not right in the signup activity. Yes, I tried uninstalling but nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with creating table in onCreate() of DatabaseHelper Class

```
db.execSQL("Create table user(Username name, email text primary key, password text, mobilenumber number, country text)");
```

In the above code, you have declared the username wrongly.Name isn't any type in db. Type of username should be text/varchar and you should include id as primary key not email because it is not best practice.  change the onCreate() like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Create table user(id INTEGER primary key, username TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT, mobilenumber INTEGER, country TEXT)");
}
```

then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax is invalid as pointed out in other answers.  The following pattern of catching the error may help as your App and database gets more complex:

[SQLException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html) is a `RuntimeException` and so the compiler does not demand you catch it - but it is thrown on SQL Error and can be very efficient and helpful at diagnosing errors:

```
try {
   db.execSQL("some invalid SQL");
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.e("onCreate","Error creating table: "+e);
}
```

Here the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) discusses exceptions thrown.

(And your insert fails because the `mobile_number` is not a valid column name (see your create table)).

(And `.close()` your `Cursor`s - will fail eventually.)